# would wearing copper rings cause any toxicity?

Tags: health

I've been wearing a copper ring in my left hand for more than 2 years and I my friend recently asked me to remove it,saying it will add some toxins into me .Is it true? Or is he is seriously kidding?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your friend is misinformed.  Copper jewelry will not cause copper toxity.  The actual exposure to copper by using a ring is quite minimal and will not cause you any trouble.  Copper toxity comes mostly from ingesting copper.  So if you eat the ring, then you might be looking at some copper related issues.  But by just wearing it the most you will have deal with is a green finger.

[Information on copper toxicity](http://drlwilson.com/articles/copper_toxicity_syndrome.htm)

Comment: Stop answering blatantly off topic questions.